# Salvar dados no banco de dados com Drag & Drop

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tendo alguns problemas para inserir uma ordenação no banco de dados, estou utilizando um sistema de Drag e Drop, que baixei na net e o sistema funciona exatamente como eu preciso e quero.

Só que eu estou com um problema para ser resolvido, que é salvar a ordem do sistema de Drag e Drop no banco de dados.

A ideia é o seguinte, o cliente quer um sistema de galerias que arraste as fotos da galeria, de modo que fique na ordem que ele determinou, o drag & drop já faz isso. Já consigo recuperar o ID, de cada imagem. Agora tudo que eu preciso é determinar um valor tipo fazer a contagem de 1 até a quantidade de imagens, tipo: se tiver 10 imagens e o cliente fez a ordenação. eu preciso listar os numeros de 1 a 10, e salvar esses numeros na tabela, no campo ordem, pra que quando eu listar as imagens no site eu ordene exatamente pela ordem.

Não sei se conseguiram entender, mais vou mostrar o trecho do meu código.

```
<div id="redips-drag">
   <?php
   $order = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

   if (isset($order['SelectOrdem']) AND $order['SelectOrdem'] == 'Salvar Ordem'):
      unset($order['SelectOrdem']);
   endif;
   ?>

<form action="" method="post">
   <table style='width:100%;'>
      <colgroup>
         <col width="250"/>
         <col width="250"/>
         <col width="250"/>
         <col width="250"/>
      </colgroup>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
         <?php
         $gbi = 0;
         $Gallery = new Read;
         $Check = new Check;
         $Gallery->ExeRead("ws_posts_gallery", "WHERE post_id = :post", "post={$postid}");

         if ($Gallery->getResult()):    
            $LoopHorizontal = 4;
            $i = 1;

            foreach ($Gallery->getResult() as $gb):
               if ($i < $LoopHorizontal):
                   $gbi++;
                   ?>
                   <td>
                   <div class="redips-drag">
                      <input type="text" name="ordem[]" value="<?= $gbi; ?>">
                      <input type="text" name="id[]" value="<?= $gb->gallery_id; ?>">
                      <?= $Check->Image('../uploads/' . $gb->gallery_image, $gbi, 146, 100); ?><br>
                      <a href="painel.php?exe=produtos/update&postid=<?= $postid; ?>&gbdel=<?= $gb->gallery_id; ?>#gbfoco" class="del btn btn-danger">Deletar</a>
                      </div>
                   </td>

                   <?php elseif ($i = $LoopHorizontal):
                   ?>

                   <td>
                   <div class="redips-drag">
                      <input type="text" name="ordem[]" value="<?= $gbi; ?>">
                      <input type="text" name="id[]" value="<?= $gb->gallery_id; ?>">
                      <?= $Check->Image('../uploads/' . $gb->gallery_image, $gbi, 146, 100); ?><br>
                      <a href="painel.php?exe=produtos/update&postid=<?= $postid; ?>&gbdel=<?= $gb->gallery_id; ?>#gbfoco" class="del btn btn-danger">Deletar</a>
                   </div>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <?php
                $i = 0;
                endif;
             $i++;
             endforeach;
          endif;
          ?>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-actions">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary green" value="Salvar Ordem" name="SelectOrdem" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Eu não sei pessoal, se eu fiz isso aí da forma correta, tipo envolvi a tabela do drag & drop em um form, para tentar recuperar os valores, mais sem sucesso.  Se alguém puder ajudar com este problema, eu fico muito grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, já fiz isso da seguinte forma:
criei uma class em uma TD para referência via jquery;
dentro dessa td criei um input com name array e a chave é o id do produto;
na hora de clicar no botão de reordenar, salvei a ordem das td através de um each no jquery, passando o indice para o valor do input chaveado com o id.
na hora  de salvar, fica a ordem certinha determinada pelo usuário

imagem Array {
 1: 0,
 15: 1,
 95: 2
...
}

exemplo:
html:

```
<td class="imagem" width="50" align="center">
 <img src='/img/imagem.png'>
<input type="hidden" name="imagens[<?= $id; ?>] ?>]" value="">
</td>
```

---

```
 function reordena(){
        $(".imagem").each(function(i){
           $(this).children().val(i);
        });

        $("#form").submit();
    }
```

php:

> foreach($_POST['imagens'] as $id => $odem){
>
> $ordem //aqui vc tem a ordem selecionada 
>   $id // aqui vc tem o id
>   }